# Alterar o valor de uma variável global dentro de uma função do mongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso alterar, por exemplo, o valor de MyVar dentro da função collection.insert?

Obrigado! ;)

Comment: Try to refer to this page: https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/node/insert/

Comment: Seja bem-vindo(a) ao SOPt. Por favor, não cole screenshots de códigos. Isso dificulta a busca. Além disso, quando colocar imagens, não omita a descrição, que é a única forma de quem usa leitores de tela entender o que tem nela.

Comment: Primeiro, vc declara a variável `var myVar = false;` e depois, o método `db.collection(...)` e `collection.insert(...)` devem ser executados, só então depois ele será alterado. Caso contrário, ele irá permanecer inalterado. e Ainda assim, ele será alterado internamente, e não fora do escopo.

Answer (score 1):

Os métodos com que estás a lidar são assíncronos.

Isso quer dizer que o código `collection.insert` é corrido, recebe um primeiro argumento `data` e o segundo argumento é uma função callback. Essa função não é corrida imediatamente. Ela só é corrida quando a BD responder. Portanto a linha de código onde tens `console.log(myVar);` é corrida **antes** do que essa callback, apesar de estar em linhas de código depois dessa callback.

Para solucionar esse problema tens de colocar todo o código que depende dessa variável dentro da callback, ou chamar código de dentro da callback passando essa variável `myVar` como argumento.

```
.insert(data, function(err, result){
    // correr aqui o código
    console.log(result);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Veja se isso resolve seu caso:

```
var sistema = {
   variable_bool : false,
   acao : function(bool) {
         sistema.variable_bool = bool;
          },
   getBool: function() {
       return sistema.variable_bool;
   }
};

var action = function(){
    sistema.acao(true);
    console.log(sistema.getBool());
};

action();
```

Um exemplo:

```
var ActionsConnection = {

database : null,
myVar : false,
collection: [],
collectionName : "MyCollection",
connectToMongoDB : function() {
         this.database.collection(ActionsConnection.collectionName, function(error, collection) {
         return collection;  
   });
},
insertDataOnMongoDB: function(db, data) {
  this.database = db;
  this.collection = this.connectToMongoDB();
  this.collection.insert(data, function(error, result) {
        ActionsConnection.setPermission(true);
  });
},
setPermission : function(bool) {
  this.myVar = bool;
},
getPermission : function() {
  return this.myVar;
}

}
ActionsConnection.insertDataOnMongoDB(db, data);
if (ActionsConnection.getPermission() == true) {
   console.log('registro cadastrado!');
}
```